# can't access the 'header' element inside my html file using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to create an HTML element using JavaScript **document.createElement("div")** and then prepend/append it in my header of the document, but below is what I'm getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQtRS.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You’ve never defined `header`. The error message is correct. You get the `<header>` element, for example, with `document.querySelector("header")`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: @jabaa any issue with images?

Comment: Yes, you can't copy the code. You can't search for the code. Handicapped users can't use screen readers. It's difficult to read on small displays. It's a Stack Overflow policy [ask] _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**"_

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never defined header. You have to initialize it first by using `var header = document.querySelector('header');`

Then you can use `header.prepend(...);`

Comment: Oh, thanks, I got it, Actually, I'm learning JS but haven't done this thing before so I didn't know that to use the elements from HTML doc, I've to deal with them like this...

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your `header.prepend` to:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].prepend(message);
```